# ssh -X on Linux to remote server running Windows

Tags: xorg

I would like to know if it's possible to install a ssh server on Windows and to connect to it from Linux with `ssh -X`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, that is possible. You may want to have a look at [Xming](https://sourceforge.net/projects/xming/) or [MobaXterm](http://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/).

Another solution might be [x2go](http://wiki.x2go.org), which is based on the NX 3.x. It also utilizes SSH but does some compression and you can either open a single `xterm` or a complete Linux Desktop.